# Angular Forms, build an Array of Objects

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to build an array of objects with Angular forms and I cannot get it to work.

Question:
How do you build an array of objects with Angular forms?

Here is what I want:

```
productForm = this.fb.group({
businessNotes: this.fb.array([
      [key: valuePair]
    ]),
});
```

Here is what I have:

```
component:

productForm = this.fb.group({
businessNotes: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        text: ['']
      })
    ]),
});

addBusinessNote() {
 let control = (<FormArray> (<FormGroup>this.productForm).get('businessNotes')).controls;
    control.push(this.fb.group({text: ['']}));
}

get businessNotes() {
return this.productForm.get('businessNotes') as FormArray;
}

html:
<div>
    <p>Business Notes:</p>
    <div formArrayName="businessNotes">
      <h3>business notes</h3> <button (click)="addBusinessNote()">Add business note</button>

      <div *ngFor="let note of productForm.controls.businessNotes.controls; let i=index ">
        <label>
          note: {{i + 1}}
          <input type="text" [formControlName]="text">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here is the output I am getting:

```
ProductAddComponent.html:69 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'businessNotes -> '
    at _throwError (forms.js:2144)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2052)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5281)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5882)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5803)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22085)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23353)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23315)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23949)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23909)
```

Comment: Angular version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div formArrayName="businessNotes">
        <h3>business notes</h3> <button (click)="addBusinessNote()">Add business note</button>
      <div *ngFor="let note of businessNotes.controls; let i=index" >
          <label>
            note: {{i + 1}}
            <input type="text" [formControl]="note.get('text')">
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I think its most upset about about the [formControlName]="text" part. Its not sure which form group its under. I think there are multiple ways around that, but I find binding to the formControl to be the most strait forward.

I think there might also be a bug in your add method. I dont think you need the array.controls here, you can push directly to the array.

Good luck!